# Handling that need to RAGE quit

Tags: stress

I really just am curious how people out there suppress their nerd rage while at work. I think I am about to make a scene and that would be very bad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ping a few people over "Instant Message" and chat for a bit, then head to the nearest store and grab a treat.  Lastly, put on a few cool tunes to lighten up the mood.  Once complete, take a deep breath and realize that it's only work, and it's not worth it to do something you might regret for years to come.

Comment: I know it's not worth pulling a Jerry Maguire, but I have been stuck on this particular problem for about 3 weeks... sigh

Answer (score 0):

Glass of water, 15 minute smoke break, and then skim engadget. Works like a charm.

Comment: ... for people who like engulfing others around them in toxic substances, at least.

Comment: maybe I should take up smoking?

Comment: You can substitute "smoke break" with "walk around the building"